# Difference between carrier and bearer

Tags: difference

Do carrier and bearer have the same meaning?

I trying to name a column in a table that registers third party goods. It looks like this:

```
| item     | owner | ???     |
| notebook | John  | Michael |
```

Where Michel is the person who brought the notebook, but the owner is John.

So, What is the best name for the column?

Comment: More context is needed. The meaning of "brought" is unclear, since this indicates a movement you have not defined. I wonder if either word is what you are looking for. Basically, a "carrier" takes something from one place to another, while a "bearer" is in possession of something.

Comment: Have you considered looking in a good dictionary? http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bearer

Comment: A carrier is an airline or ship. The best name is TPGR: third party goods registrant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use

> deliverer
>   delivery

if you are trying to keep a distinction between he *supplier* and the *delivery* company.

Amazon might use the word

> fulfillment

But that may have meaning beyond only the person who made the delivery.